# Node JS security when invoking an unknown function

Tags: node.js

I have a case where I need to run on the server a dynamic function ( in string representation) I receive from the client that produces data:

```
const functionFromClient = `return { id: 1 }`;

const getData = new Function('params', functionFromClient);

console.log(getData(params));
```

Do we have a way to sanitize the function so that it doesn't run code that may harm the server?

Comment: There is no simple way to sanitize foreign code to be safe in nodejs as random code has full access to the system via nodejs.  The only workable solution I know of is to run the code in a separate and sand-boxed VM.

Comment: If you tell us what the overall problem is and why you are introducing foreign code, then perhaps we can offer some other solution that wouldn't have these vulnerabilities.  For example, a solution where the client supplies data that can be processed by your code on the server can typically be generalized to cover a lot of cases.

Comment: @jfriend00 We have a case where the user can pass a dynamic function. The server calls the function and passes the arguments. This cannot be done in the client as we'll have to load the libraries that generate the arguments for this function on the client, which is a heavy task.

Comment: I'd suggest you change that architecture so that the user passes data that describes what they wish to do and your server contains code that can handle all possible permutations for the data they pass.  You simply cannot safely run code on your server that is given to you by the client.  You need a different design.  If it's your client code, then all possible code that the client might generate is known to you and you can move that logic to the server and the client can pass you some data that indicates which type of code they want to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to sanitize foreign code to be safe when running in nodejs as random code has full access to the system via nodejs. The only workable solution for running on your server I know of is to run the code in a separate and sand-boxed VM.

I'd suggest you change your architecture so that the client passes data that describes what they wish to do and your server contains code that can handle all possible permutations for the data they pass and run the appropriate code locally to process that data.

You simply cannot safely run code on your server that is given to you by the client. You need a different design. If it's your client code, then all possible code that the client might generate is known to you and you can move that logic to the server and the client can pass you some data that indicates which type of code they want to execute and the server can run the correct algorithm to process that data.  This is the way that problems like this are usually solved in a safe manner.

If you truly want to safely run code in nodejs that an actual human user writes, then you have to either run it in the client's own browser or run it in some separate process from your server in some type of VM sandbox that prevents the code from doing any harm.